# Remove permissions from player

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am working on a spigot 1.8 plugin that manages permissions. The problem is when a staff member joins the server lags for about 10 seconds and they wait in the login screen for a while, but if normal players join they join instantly and don't lag.

I managed to limit it down to the method that removes permissions that are denied to the user.

My methods are

```
public void removePermission(String permission){
    for (PermissionAttachmentInfo paInfo : getEffectivePermissions()) {
        if (paInfo.getAttachment() != null && paInfo.getAttachment().getPlugin().equals(ServerCore.getPlugin())) {
            paInfo.getAttachment().unsetPermission(permission);
            paInfo.getAttachment().setPermission(permission, false);
        }
    }
}

public Set<PermissionAttachmentInfo> getEffectivePermissions(){
    return player.getEffectivePermissions();
}
```

Is there a better way to remove permissions from users without causing so much lag?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in permisison plugins, but when you remove a permission, you should just use unsetPermission, don't use setPermission.

The removePermission() method should NOT be called on the player join event, so I suggest posting that code instead of the method you posted.

Also, getEffectivePermissions() is just a useless method, if a method is less than one line its better to just delete it or make it a variable.